# How do I access the AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in Django's template?

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I can do this...and it prints the username.

```
{{ user.username }}
```

How can I print one of the field in my UserDetails model? (that's my AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE)

```
{{ user.get_profile().avatar_link }}???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

{{ user.get_profile.avatar_link }}